# recursively get CSS from an element and all the childs

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
getRecursiveCSS(document.getElementById('#menubar'))
```

And I would like it to return a string of CSS, for the main element and all the childs.

This is what I have tried: (does not work)

```
function fullPath(el){
  var names = [];
  while (el.parentNode){
    if (el.id){
      names.unshift('#'+el.id);
      break;
    }else{
      if (el==el.ownerDocument.documentElement) names.unshift(el.tagName);
      else{
        for (var c=1,e=el;e.previousElementSibling;e=e.previousElementSibling,c++);
        names.unshift(el.tagName+":nth-child("+c+")");
      }
      el=el.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return names.join(" > ");
}

function styleRecursive(elements, css) {
    elements = Object.prototype.toString.call(elements) === '[object Array]' ? elements: [elements];
    if (elements.length == 0 || typeof elements[0] == 'undefined')
        return css;

    if (typeof elements[0].querySelector == 'undefined')
        return css

    if (typeof css == 'undefined')
        css = fullPath(elements[0]) + '{' + getComputedStyle(elements[0]).cssText + '}';
    else
        css += fullPath(elements[0]) + '{' + getComputedStyle(elements[0]).cssText + '}';

    _elements = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < elements[i].childNodes.length; ii++)
            _elements.push(elements[i].childNodes[ii]);
    }

    return styleRecursive(_elements, css);
};
```

Comment: Hi, i write a solution that traverse all children nodes and find all css attributes/properties and will push them into an array, BUT i am jQuery expert so i write it in jQuery. Is this pure js question or its not problem to see jQuery approach?

Comment: @ColinCline Pure JS

Comment: a pure js answer added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i came up with a solution that maybe give you idea about how improve your code. In order to test driving this code I've made an element that have some children in different depths and this code traverse all children by their depth in **recursive** way to find/get their `css`. After that, all founded `css` plus the element name will storage in an object (`JSON` like) for later use.

**Please Note**: 
1) This code is not bullet proof so you need to add a lot of conditions/checker to make it work for all kind of situations.
2) Tested in chrome.
3) Limited to classes for finding element and its children (easy to upgrade for ids and tags support)

**Output**:

```
one : {
  display: "block",
  position: "relative"
}
two : {
  display: "inline-block",
  font-family: "Montserrat"
}
three_1 : {
  display: "table",
  position: "absolute",
  left: "0px"
}
four_1 : {
  display: "table-cell",
  position: "relative"
}
three_2 : {
  display: "table",
  position: "absolute",
  right: "0px"
}
four_2 : {
  display: "table-cell",
  position: "relative"
}
```

**HTML**(Sample):

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three_1">
            <div class="four_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="three_2">
            <div class="four_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**(Sample):

```
.one {display:block;position:relative;}
.two {display:inline-block;font-family:'Montserrat';}
.three_1 {display:table;position:absolute;left:0;}
.three_2 {display:table;position:absolute;right:0;}
.four_1 {display:table-cell;position:relative;}
.four_2 {display:table-cell;position:relative;}
```

**JS**:

```
function convertObjlike(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    css = css.split("; ");
    for (var i in css) {
        var l = css[i].split(": ");
        s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
    }
    return s;
}

function getCss(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a === rules[r].selectorText) {
                o = convertObjlike(rules[r].style.cssText);
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

var anObject = {};
function styleRecursive(element){
  anObject[element.className] = (getCss('.'+element.className));
  var children = element.children;

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    styleRecursive(children[i])
  }
}

styleRecursive( document.querySelector('.one') );
console.log(anObject);
```

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8b4Lfj46/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: note that this solution returns the HTML copy, and not the CSS 'file'.

Here is my attempt. It gets every computed style of the element and stores it in the `style` attribute. It also removes the `class` attribute since in most cases it is used only for setting those styles (you can remove the `removeAttribute` call if you want). And it iterate over its children to compute recursively the resulting HTML.

The resulting HTML is huge, as a lot of styles are just the default value, and it isn't optimized for inherit styles, so every child gets all its styles again. Font faces must be imported/registred separately.

Hover effects and media queries does not get copied, since the `getComputedStyle` captures only the current state of the node. Relative units like `vw`, `vh`, `%`, etc, also gets fixed to the current absolute value. For the same reason, variables are lost and its values are used instead.

```js
function getElemHtml(elem) {
    let style = [], computed = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
    for (const attr of computed) style.push(`${attr}:${computed[attr]}`)
    let clone = elem.cloneNode()
    clone.setAttribute('style', style.join(";"))
    clone.removeAttribute('class')
    let childrenHTML = ''
    for (const child of elem.childNodes) childrenHTML += child.nodeType === Element.ELEMENT_NODE ? getElemHtml(child) : child.nodeType === Element.TEXT_NODE ? child.nodeValue : ''
    clone.innerHTML = childrenHTML
    return clone.outerHTML
}

const elem = document.querySelector("p")
const elemHtml = getElemHtml(elem)
document.querySelector("code").innerText = elemHtml
```

```css
p {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font: 2rem/2 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}

pre, code {
  width: 90vw;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>

<pre><code></code></pre>
```

Comment: Now I'm thinking that might be great to skip script tags...